# Locate a specific string after a previous locate command

Tags: php, mysql, contao, jquery-isotope

So I got my "little" code here:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Verbindung
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pw', 'db');

// search stuff
// Treuhandbetrag case 1
$suchstringanfang_treuhand1 = 'treuhand_betrag\"';
$suchstringende_treuhand1 = '\";';

// Treuhandbetrag case 2
$suchstringanfang_treuhand2 = 'treuhand_price\"';
$suchstringende_treuhand2 = '\";';

//queries
//Treuhandabfrage case 1
$query_treuhand1 = "SELECT SUBSTRING(LEFT(configuration, LOCATE('$suchstringende_treuhand1', configuration) +0), LOCATE('$suchstringanfang_treuhand1', configuration) +0, 100)
FROM tl_iso_product_collection_item
WHERE LOCATE('$suchstringende_treuhand1', configuration) > 0
AND LOCATE('$suchstringanfang_treuhand1', configuration) > 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

//Treuhandabfrage case 2
$query_treuhand2 = "SELECT SUBSTRING(LEFT(configuration, LOCATE('$suchstringende_treuhand2', configuration) +0), LOCATE('$suchstringanfang_treuhand2', configuration) +0, 100)
FROM tl_iso_product_collection_item
WHERE LOCATE('$suchstringende_treuhand2', configuration) > 0
AND LOCATE('$suchstringanfang_treuhand2', configuration) > 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

//results
// Treuhandbetrag
$result_treuhand1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query_treuhand1);
$result_treuhand2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query_treuhand2);

//Display results
if($result_treuhand2 === FALSE) { 
    echo mysqli_error($connection);
} else
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_treuhand2)){
print_r($row[0]);
}

//Close connection
mysqli_close($connection); 
?>
```

What I'm basically trying to do is locate a string between

treuhand_betrag

and the NEXT occuring

";

This is because the shop stores all attribute-data in one TEXT-field in the database. I know this is an emergency solution, but I desperately need some halp. With my code so far it won't give me any results back. If I replace "; trough something unique, like 'treuhand_price', which occurs only once in the field, I do get the desired result.

How the TEXT-field might look:
If someone gives all information u can expect the field to contain the following for example:

```
a:14:{s:6:"roller";s:1:"9";s:16:"treuhand_abfrage";s:2:"37";s:15:"treuhand_betrag";s:4:"2000";s:13:"treuhand_price";s:2:"35";s:11:"abhol_firma";s:18:"NichtdieselbeFirma";s:13:"abhol_vorname";s:14:"AndererVorname";s:14:"abhol_nachname";s:15:"AndererNachname";s:12:"abhol_str_nr";s:15:"AndereStraße 7";s:9:"abhol_plz";s:6:"456465";s:9:"abhol_ort";s:12:"Dschingistan";s:10:"abhol_land";s:3:"Bla";s:13:"abhol_telefon";s:6:"564654";s:11:"abhol_email";s:10:"d.web@d.de";s:11:"bemerkungen";s:5:"aeawe";}
```

If someone doesn't care much and doesn't give away too much information:

```
a:8:{s:6:"roller";s:1:"9";s:16:"treuhand_abfrage";s:2:"36";s:13:"treuhand_price";s:2:"35";s:13:"abhol_vorname";s:5:"Deniz";s:14:"abhol_nachname";s:5:"Cetin";s:12:"abhol_str_nr";s:10:"straße 38";s:9:"abhol_plz";s:5:"90461";s:9:"abhol_ort";s:9:"Nürnberg";}
```

I would be very glad about some help or hints! Thanks in advance!

Comment: i not realy understand you. Do you want to select the value 2000 behind the first treuhand_betrag ?

Comment: ^ Yes exactly. But also all the values behind the other abhol_* fields.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want. its a little bit tricky. So i reverse the string (and the search string) to get the rest from it with SUBSTR_INDEX. I ha change your fieldname to the STRING in this sample

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   REVERSE('a:14:{s:6:"roller";s:1:"9";s:16:"treuhand_abfrage";s:2:"37";s:15:"treuhand_betrag";s:4:"2000";s:13:"treuhand_price";s:2:"35";s:11:"abhol_firma";s:18:"NichtdieselbeFirma";s:13:"abhol_vorname";s:14:"AndererVorname";s:14:"abhol_nachname";s:15:"AndererNachname";s:12:"abhol_str_nr";s:15:"AndereStraße 7";s:9:"abhol_plz";s:6:"456465";s:9:"abhol_ort";s:12:"Dschingistan";s:10:"abhol_land";s:3:"Bla";s:13:"abhol_telefon";s:6:"564654";s:11:"abhol_email";s:10:"d.web@d.de";s:11:"bemerkungen";s:5:"aeawe";}')
    ,'garteb_dnahuert'
    ,1),';"',-2)),'"',-1);
```

**Result**

2000

please let me know if it what you search for

i copy from my answer into a mysql client:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT
    ->   SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(
    ->    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    ->    REVERSE('a:14:{s:6:"roller";s:1:"9";s:16:"treuhand_abfrage";s:2:"37";s:15:"treuhand_betrag";s:4:"2000";s:13:"treuhand_price";s:2:"35";s:11:"abhol_firma";s:18:"NichtdieselbeFirma";s:13:"abhol_vorname";s:14:"AndererVorname";s:14:"abhol_nachname";s:15:"AndererNachname";s:12:"abhol_str_nr";s:15:"AndereStraße 7";s:9:"abhol_plz";s:6:"456465";s:9:"abhol_ort";s:12:"Dschingistan";s:10:"abhol_land";s:3:"Bla";s:13:"abhol_telefon";s:6:"564654";s:11:"abhol_email";s:10:"d.web@d.de";s:11:"bemerkungen";s:5:"aeawe";}')
    ->     ,'garteb_dnahuert'
    ->     ,1),';"',-2)),'"',-1);
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   REVERSE('a:14:{s:6:"roller";s:1:"9";s:16:"treuhand_abfrage";s:2:"37";s:15:"treuhand_betrag";s:4:"2000";s:13:"treuhand_price";s:2:"35";s:11:"abhol_firma";s:18:"NichtdieselbeFirma";s:13:"abhol_v |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: that didn't do the trick, I get an error saying "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'roller' "
Still, I'm more looking for a more specific solution: I'm looking for, let's say, something between ' treuhand_betrag\" ' and the following ' \"; which would be ' ;s:4:"2000 ', right? How do I get to this result?

Comment: @Deniz Gelion - i have add in my answer

Comment: change the last -1 to -2 to get ;s:4:"2000

Comment: That was my bad, didn't escape the strings first. It does work, but still isn't the solution I'm looking for. I already have a code working like that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177474/how-do-i-correctly-implement-this-mysql-query-into-a-php-file-and-display-the-re